# Remove indexes of multidimensional array to convert to a list of many one dimensional arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies for vague questioning, I'm fairly new. I've been searching but can't seem to find the solution that fits my scenario.

I am trying to store the output of a looped mysql query as a variable to be used outside the loop, exactly as it would be if I were to print_r the result within the loop. I am trying to save on overhead as I have inherited a function which uses this large dataset frequently and am trying to reduce the calls to the database by saving the output instead of querying database each time.

Currently I have -

```
$data = array();
$sql = mysqli_query($con, SELECT * FROM my_table);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
  $data[] = $row;
}
print_r($data);
```

which is resulting in:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => john [age] => 44  ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => paul [age] => 30  )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => george [age] => 25  )
)
```

BUT i am needing an output like this, i.e. without top indexes...

```
$output =

Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => john [age] => 44  ) 
Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => paul [age] => 30  )
Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => george [age] => 25  ) ;
```

It is late and my brain eludes me, many thanks for any pointers.

EDIT:
Will take a mulligan on this one, turns out my problem was a formatting one where I did not escape ($) sign when assigning it as a variable whilst saving the output to file. Thanks all for your replies and setting me straight

Comment: You **need** the top-level indexes. Otherwise you have to have multiple variables to store the data in e.g. `$data0`, `$data1` etc. You can just process the saved data using a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Exactly right! Thanks Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result and the expected result is bascially the same thing because as @Nick pointed out **you need to have top level keys** (0,1,2). (How would you else identify which id belongs to john and to paul and to george?)

It's simply not possible to **store** an array like this:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => john [age] => 44  ) 
Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => paul [age] => 30  )
Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => george [age] => 25  )
```

**It must be stored like this:** (with top level keys (in this case:0,1 and 2))

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => john [age] => 44  ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => paul [age] => 30  )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => george [age] => 25  )
)
```

The value of `$data[0]['name']` would be john, the value of `$data[1]['name']` would be paul etc.

If you refer to `$data[0]` it contains the array: `Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => john [age] => 44  )`

If you refer to `$data[1]` it contains the array: `Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => paul [age] => 30  )`
etc

It's not possible to **store** the values as you want but it is of course possible to have the output as you wish:

```
//$data_value is an array in every row 
foreach($data as $data_value) {
    print_r($data_value);
}
```

which would produce the output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => john
    [age] => 44
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => paul
    [age] => 30
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => george
    [age] => 25
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and detailed explanation. Good to know that what I was trying was not possible and probably for good reason!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
$data = [];
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    foreach( $row as $field => $value) {
        $data[$i][$field] = $value:
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($data)
```

Comment: There would still be top indexes. this solution actually does not differ from the OP's in terms of the result output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, an interesting approach which I'm sure will come in handy at some point but yes, as @bestprogrammerintheworld pointed out, same output as the original

Comment: @midget it's not interesting. Arrays always have some kind of key for each value, or they could never be accessed, just because print_r prints 0 - a, 1 - b, 3 - c doesn't mean it isn't [a,b,c]

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 - that's the whole point. They need keys (top level keys in this case).

Comment: It's sounds like he wants it in JSON @bestprogrammerintheworld

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 - no it does not?

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 by interesting I meant clever to a newbie like myself. Was just interesting that the result was the same as before. In any case, it was a simple fix as explained in my edit.